# SQL Server 2008 STFilter Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial-query, spatial-index

Let me preface this by saying that I'm new to spatial indexes. I've got a sproc that I know is using my spatial index (takes up 1% of the query), however a Filter is slowing my query down (takes up 52% of the query). I'm struggling to figure out how to speed this up as I don't have many records returning (roughly 1000).

**SCENARIO**

I have a table of orders. Each record has a `Zipcode` of where the product originates from, and a `Zipcode` of where the product is being shipped to.

I also have a table of all the Zipcodes in the country along with the `GEOGRAPHY`point of the zipcode based on lat/long (Already calculated as a column in the table).

I need to get all of the orders that originate from within a 75 mile radius of a passed in Zipcode and are shipped to a Zipcode within 75 miles of a passed in destination zipcode.

Here's the SQL I have. It works, but I need to get it faster. I don't think it should be taking more than 1 second.

```
DECLARE 
    @oCenterPoint GEOGRAPHY,
    @dCenterPoint GEOGRAPHY,
    @originCircle GEOGRAPHY,
    @destCircle GEOGRAPHY,
    @radiusInMeters DECIMAL

SELECT @oCenterPoint=GeographyPoint FROM MyZipcodeTable WHERE Zipcode=@prmOriginZip
SELECT @dCenterPoint=GeographyPoint FROM MyZipcodeTable WHERE Zipcode=@prmDestZip
SET @radiusInMeters = 75 * 1609.344

/* build the two circles to use STIntersects() function */
SET @originCircle = @oCenterPoint.Reduce(400).STBuffer(@radiusInMeters).Reduce(1000)
SET @destCircle = @dCenterPoint.Reduce(400).STBuffer(@radiusInMeters).Reduce(1000)


/* get our zips that are in our origin radius */
CREATE TABLE #oZips (Zipcode VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO #oZips ( Zipcode )
SELECT z.Zipcode
FROM MyZipcodeTable  z
WHERE @originCircle.STIntersects(z.GeographyPoint)=1

/* get our zips that are in our destination radius */
CREATE TABLE #dZips (Zipcode VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)  
INSERT INTO #dZips ( Zipcode )
SELECT z.Zipcode
FROM MyZipcodeTable  z
WHERE @destCircle.STIntersects(z.GeographyPoint)=1
```

This is the slowest part of the query. Inner joining my Orders table to these origin and destination zip tables is quick. Inserting the valid zipcodes is what is causing a performance issue. Like I said above, it's using a spatial index, but up the execution plan, there's a Filter that costs 52%. It's doing something with a CASE statement which must be a part of the STIntersects() function.

Also, Even though it's using my spatial index, I see it using my Clustered index as well with takes 37% of the query. I don't have an included column on my spatial index. Not sure if you can, or how I get around that.

Is there any red flags that jump out at anyone? Any redirection is appreciated!

Comment: Include the DDL of the Orders table. And the actual execution plan using https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: `WHERE @destCircle.STDistance(z.GeographyPoint)=1`? Is that a typo (i.e. do you mean `STIntersects`)?

Comment: @BenThul Correct - I meant STIntersects. I've been trying so many different things to tweak the performance, haha.

Comment: Have you got a spatial index defined on the `GeographyPoint` column?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I do. And the spatial index is being used, I've confirmed this using a temp sproc as well as going into the sproc cache and making sure.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever All the indexes are being used properly I believe. I'm to the point to where I'm trying to figure out how to reduce the number of reads on each table. For example, my spatial index's ```estimated number of rows``` is 8,053 but the actual is 849. At the same time, I'm getting 8496 ```logical reads``` on that index. I'm struggling to figure out how to reduce that number.

Comment: @Maxhar Here's the plan of the slowest part of the query which is me trying to insert the valid zipcodes into a temp table. Keep in mind that this table has nearly 900k zipcodes because we have to accommodate for Canada as well as the US. 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bkx84jHgm